# ASP.NET: Session.IsNewSession false after forms timeout, but should be true?

Tags: asp.net, session-timeout

I'm working to set up/correct my session timeout code, and have consulted numerous articles like [this one](http://aspalliance.com/520_Detecting_ASPNET_Session_Timeouts.2) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427264/asp-net-session-timeout-detection-is-session-isnewsession-and-sessioncookie-dete) for ideas on how best to do this. The solution to detecting a session timeout that I continue to see over and over is to first check the Session.IsNewSession property for true, and if so, then check to see if a session cookie already exists. I guess the logic here is that the user has ended their last session that timed out, started a new session, but the old cookie wasn't yet removed. The code for those checks looks like this:

```
if (Context.Session != null)
{
    if (Session.IsNewSession)
    {
        string szCookieHeader = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
        if ((null != szCookieHeader) && (szCookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
        {
            Response.Redirect("sessionTimeout.htm"); // or whatever code to handle timeout
        }  
    } 
}
```

Now I'm currently working with a Session timeout value of 120 minutes, and a Forms timeout value of 60 mins. Those two lines from my web.config file, resepectively, are here:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" timeout="120" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Customer" timeout="60" name=".ASPXAUTH" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
</authentication>
```

So after 60 minutes (I set it to 1 to test), I make a request to the server, and I'm automatically redirected to /Home/Customer, I assume due to the 'loginURL' value in my web.config line.

The problem is that the session does not end, and all of my session timeout checks are in the Home/Customer action (I use MVC). So I'm redirected to Home/Customer, and I run through the checks above, but when I get to Session.IsNewSession, it's false, because the session is still alive (I assume because I'm still within the 120 minutes I have set).

So, finally, my question. Does this whole session-timeout-checking scheme only work when the actual *Session* times out? Or can I make it work for *Forms* timeouts as well? Maybe the solution is to set my Session timeout value as the same as the Forms timeout value?

Answer (score 2):

The ASP.NET session cookie and the Forms authentication cookie are actually completely different cookies - if your app pool recycles, for instance, your user will lose their session but not their login identity (assuming you're using in-proc session). The only way your code would be hit, I think, is if your session timeout was less than your forms timeout. Any other way, and you will be redirected to the login page before you hit the session timeout code.

Another option would be to move the session timeout code to your login page.

A third would be to handle the check within your global.asax.

Comment: Currently those checks are in the controller action that runs when the user hits the page that allows them to log in (Home/Customer), which I would consider to be the login page, unless you're talking about something different. Can you elaborate a bit on the global.asax option?

Comment: No, you're right. It just means that you won't always get IsNewSession to be true; only when the user had been idling more than 120 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I just did some test of what user ***John Christensen*** said about

> if your session timeout was less than your forms timeout.

**web.config**

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login"  defaultUrl="~/Account/Login" name="MyPortalAuth" timeout="2" />
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
```

And it seems it is working solution.

**C# filter attribute**

```
public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

            // check if session is supported
            if (ctx.Session != null)
            {
                // check if a new session id was generated
                if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
                {
                    // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must
                    // have timed out
                    string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                    if ((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                    {

                        if (ctx.Request.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                        }
                        RedirectResult rr = new RedirectResult(loginUrl);
                        filterContext.Result = rr;
                        //ctx.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Logon");

                    }
                }                
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Comment: HOW-TO use **ActionFilter** ?